# How to make part of a banner clickable in layer slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the layerslider on my home page to show several banners, and I want the user to click on the text on each banner to redirect them to a different page, so I need to specify that text as a link and to keep the design responsive.  How can I do that?

here is the slider demo page:

http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/

My

```
<div id="layerslider" style="width: 100%; height: 396px; visibility: visible;" class="ls-container ls-v5">
            <!-- slide one start -->
            <div class="ls-inner" style="width: 1903px; height: 396px; background-color: transparent;"><div class="ls-lt-container ls-overflow-hidden" style="width: 1903px; height: 396px; display: block;"></div><div class="ls-slide" data-ls="slidedelay: 8000;transition2d:5;timeshift:-1000;" style="width: 0px; height: 396px; visibility: visible; display: none; left: 0px; right: auto; top: 0px; bottom: auto;">

                <!-- slide background image -->
                <img src="./Home2_files/slide1.jpg" class="ls-bg ls-preloaded" alt="Slide background" style="z-index:0; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; width: 1903px; height: 470.993px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -37.4963px; visibility: hidden;"><div class="ls-gpuhack" style="width: auto; height: auto; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; left: 301.5px; top: 0px;">
                <a href="MY_URL_link" class="link"></a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to know what the id/class is for the text. I am going to use class="text" for this example because you didn't provide any classes/ids for the words. Also, the words are going to be inside a div, so it would be `<div class="text">Text goes here</div>`.

With jQuery, you could possible do this:

```
$("document").ready(function{
    $(".text").click({
        $(location).attr('href', 'your url here');
    });
});
```

then, you could use this code as many times as needed, like so:

```
$("document").ready(function{
    $(".text").click({
        $(location).attr('href', 'your url here');
    });
    $(".text2").click({
        $(location).attr('href', 'your url here');
    });
});
```

the text doesn't have to be a url, as long as there is a div surrounding it.

Comment: your question is unclear, so it is difficult to understand it.

Comment: For example, one of my banners will have this message: "We provide the best service. Learn More" the learn more is clickable as "Learn more" is embedded into the banner image and it is not a div class. how can I do that?

Comment: you are saying that the words are part of the banner, like part of an image?

Comment: yes, part of the image so I need to make that part of the image clickable....how?

Comment: i don't think that is possible

Comment: why?? is it because of the layerslider? Do you have a better slider? how come amazon managed to make it work in thier banner? https://aws.amazon.com/

Comment: Well, I don't think it is possible to make part of an image clickable unless there is a div positioned in a specific place on top of the image. The image is only 1 object, and just it by itself could not detect the click in one area and not the other.